# How can I quickly extract rows based on content in a specific content in a fixed width text file using command line tools?

Tags: command-line, awk, sed, grep

I have a large text file (> 4 gb) which is in fixed-width format. I want to get a subset of that file based on content in specific columns. What would be the fastest way to do this?

For example the file will have the following format:

```
Column width 1 = 3
Column width 2 = 3
Column width 3 = 2
Column width 4 = 2
Column width 5 = 1
Column width 6 = 2
Column width 7 = 2
Column width 8 = 2
Colwidth 9 = 2
```

And a line of the file might look like:

```
150-9912 17 7 1 0 0
```

If I wanted to search based on the values of column 2 (e.g. where value of column 2 == -99), what would be the most efficient way to do this? I have multiple files ~ 4GB in size with close to 10 million lines in each file. Appreciate the help!

Comment: It depends. Do you need to do it just once, or is this what your application is normally doing?

Comment: I want to extract those rows into a new file and analyze that subset of data.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. This is a one time use script.

Comment: Then I would simply use `awk '$2==-99' big_file`

Comment: Do you have to specify column width? Some columns are blank.

Comment: If they are blank they are not equal to `-99`

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 2 2 1 2 2 2 2"} $2==-99'
```

The above will get you well on the way.